# Resonance curve of oscillating curcuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

I took a resonance curve (see below) for different (series) oscillating curcuits plotting I:f and found that the amplitude differs for different values of C and L. Why exactly is that?

[image]

Blue specs: $L=4.5mH,\ C=4.7\mu F$

Green specs: $L=4.5mH,\ C=1\mu F$

Purple specs: $L=18mH,\ C=1\mu F$

Picture of my measuring:

[image]

Comment: Think that you may need to provide more information on the resonant circuit and the graph. Was it a parallel or series resonant circuit? What kind of ac voltage or current source was used to drive it? What was the value of the resistance in the circuit? What is being plotted on the vertical scale of this graph?

Comment: It was a series resonant circuit and there was no resistance involved (apart from the inner resistance of the coil). I plotted the current vs. the frequency as seen in the plot above, since it's a series curcuit.
As for the voltage used to drive it: I don't have that information precisely but it probably was in between 0-7V. I added a picture of my measuring installation if that helps.

Comment: But if you compare blue and green the inductor resistance stayed the same and only the capacity changed.

Comment: Well, even small resistances have a big effect on the appearance of resonance curves because if there was really zero resistance then the peaks of these resonance curves would shoot up to infinity at resonance. What I don't understand offhand is why blue and purple curves have such different amplitudes even though they have very similar frequencies. The current peaks of these two curves correspond to the ac source driving nominally zero resistance loads (since the circuits are both at their respective resonant frequencies), so it seems that the amplitudes should be about the same.

Comment: Oh, hold on. I think I know why the amplitude of the purple curve is so much smaller than that of the blue curve. The purple curve used an inductor of 18 mH while that of the blue curve used an inductor of 4.5 mH. Since the 18 mH inductor was probably made by simply wrapping more wire than the 4.5 mH inductor, the 18 mH inductor should have a higher resistance then the 4.5 mH inductor - by about a factor of 4 if the coil constructions are similar. That factor of 4 is consistent with the amplitude difference between the purple and blue curves.

Comment: Let's say A is the amplitude. We can deduce from the curves:
$C_1>C_2\implies A_1>A_2$ and
$L_1>L_2\implies A_1<A_2$

So for blue and purple:
$C_b>C_p\implies A_b>A_p$ and
$L_b<L_p\implies A_p<A_b$ 

In conjunction we get $A_b >>A_p$. It seems to make sense to me if we can explain the effect of C and L on the amplitude A.

Comment: No, when the circuit is at its resonance, the reactances of the inductor and capacitor cancel each other out and the current is determined by just the value of the resistance in the circuit.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. So how can this be explained then? I got another graphic that shows exactly the same result: As L is constant, for decreasing C we get decreasing amplitudes.

Comment: Are you measuring the amplitude of the driving voltage when on resonance to make sure that it is the same for each combination of L & C?

Comment: No, I don't. As you can see, the measuring tool is basically a black box. I plug it in and tell it to vary the frequency of the AC while holding the amplitude constant but I'm not additionally measuring anything.

Comment: "So how can this be explained then? I got another graphic that shows exactly the same result: As L is constant, for decreasing C we get decreasing amplitudes." - My guess would be that the smaller capacitors that you're using have slightly more resistance in the wire leads, capacitor foil, etc.. Remember that your L's and C's are not pure L's and C's. All real L's and C's have some (small) resistance, and at a resonance peak the resistance is what determines the peak amplitude since the reactances of the L and C cancel each other out at resonance.